# CSS3 image rotating spinner in JS for non CSS3 browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I have a rotating image spinner that looks fantastic...in browsers that support it.
it can be seen at kingpetroleum.co.uk/background.php - it's in the top corner.

I need to somehow create the same effect for users that are using browsers that can't display it.

I'm not great with javascript so would be hoping on finding a good tutorial / guide etc but after a bit of googling I've not come up with anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [modernizr.com](http://modernizr.com/) is the answer

Comment: @Mr.Alien - when I tried to use it before it wouldn't work...Could you explain how it shoudl be used?

Comment: @Mr.Alien is that possible to do css3 in modenizer js??

Answer (score -1):

If your issue is very old browsers support, and for such a simple animation, you can use an animated gif. [Here](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2392701,00.asp) are some links that show how to create one. It is a very old technology supported by almost any browser out there.